# Why regex in java is behaving differently for different example?

Tags: java, regex, split

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       String s = sc.nextLine().trim();
       s= s.replaceAll("\\++"," + ");
       Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+|\\d+|[\\(\\*\\)/%]");
       Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
       while(m.find()){
           String str=m.group();
           s= s.replace(m.group()," "+str+" ").trim();
       }
      String[] str=s.split(" +");
      for(String s1:str) System.out.print(s1+",");
```

if `s=22*(7-9` output is: **22,*,(,7,-,9,**

if `s=12*(4-2`   output is:**1,2,*,(,4,-,2,**

Why digits of 12 got separated in  second example?
Help me if someone knows about it

Comment: It is working for me. Please see [**this**](https://onlinegdb.com/SyxxG7G6U)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because there are two `2` in the last expression. When you get the last `2`, you add spaces around all `2`s, so it leads to `12` to be split.